# sort an array in php not working

Tags: php, sorting

I want to sort an array. My array look like this

```
    Array ( [bookid] => 16 [book_name] => 22 [created_date] => 16 [hash_key] => 18 )
```

I want to sort by value like

```
   Array (  [book_name] => 22 [hash_key] => 18 [created_date] => 16  [bookid] => 16)
```

if any one know about this please help me.

Comment: "Not working" implies that you've already wrote some code which has a problem. That does not seem to match your actual question. In fact, there isn't even a question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use arsort

```
<?php
$your_array = array(
                      "bookid" => 16,
                      "book_name" => 22,
                      "created_date" => 16,
                      "hash_key" => 18
                    );  
arsort($your_array);
print_r($your_array);                  
?>
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [book_name] => 22
    [hash_key] => 18
    [created_date] => 16
    [bookid] => 16
)
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/176039)**